# Библеотека System.Linq.Dynamic;

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, linq, ado.net

Кто-нибудь имел дело с данной библиотекой ?

Подскажите, как правильно с помощью нее осуществить динамическое соединение двух DataTable?

**UPD:**

```
  var res2 = newDT.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().Join(oldDT.AsEnumerable(), "\"t2\"",
            "\"t2\"",
            "new (\"t2\" as TMP)");
```

Вот этот код у меня вызывает ошибку.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[DynamicClass1]' to type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

**UPD**

`newDT` и `oldDT` - это 2 DataTable.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: какая версия библиотеки?

Comment: 1.1.14 версия...

Comment: добавьте описание `newDT` и `oldDT`

Comment: добавил пояснение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37243/discussion-between-grundy-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 2):

В данном коде несколько ошибок:

В качестве ключей для *inner* и *outer* коллекций используются константные строки, таким образом даже если бы все работало - в результате выбирались бы *все* строки.
Для решения необходимо использовать объект `it` который предоставляется по умолчанию в селекторах. Его можно не указывать если обращение идет к полям объекта, но в данном случае у `DataRow` нет нужных полей, а есть только индексатор.
Поэтому код селекторов должен поменяться на

```
"it[\"t\"]"
```

где `t` - это название столбца, который выбирается.

Далее с результатом. Для селектора результата `DynamicLinq` предоставляет два параметра по умолчанию: `inner` и `outer` в них соответственно хранятся элементы внутренней и внешней коллекций подходящие под условия join. Таким образом результирующий селектор может выглядеть так:

```
"new (outer[\"t\"] as TMP)"
```

где `t` - это название столбца, который выбирается. `outer` в данном случае это `DataRow` из первой таблицы.

И, наконец, основная причина ошибки:

в библиотеке присутствует **два** метода `Join`

```
public static IQueryable Join(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable inner, string outerKeySelector, string innerKeySelector, string resultSelector, params object[] args)

public static IQueryable<TElement> Join<TElement>(this IQueryable<TElement> outer, IEnumerable<TElement> inner, string outerKeySelector, string innerKeySelector, string resultSelector, params object[] args)
```

Как можно заметить первый для non-generic IQueryable, второй для generic IQueryable.

Проблема в том, что при вызове

```
newDT.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
```

Полученная коллекция `IQueryable<DataRow>` и соответственно выбирается вторая перегрузка. Если обратить внимание на возвращаемое значение, то можно заметить, что тип элемента совпадает с исходным типом в коллекции. Таким образом, когда в результате выполнения получалась коллекция с другим типом элемента возникала ошибка при приведении.

Чтобы решить это, нужно пользоваться второй перегрузкой. Для этого, как вариант, можно привести результат `AsQueryable` к non-generic интерфейсу

```
((IQueryable)newDT.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable())
```

В итоге выражение может выглядеть так:

```
var res2 = ((IQueryable)newDT.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()).Join(oldDT.AsEnumerable(), 
        "it[\"t2\"]",
        "it[\"t2\"]",
        "new (outer[\"t2\"] as TMP)");
```